# Parsing require statements in html file with webpack

Tags: webpack

I am trying to require html partials from within html files. I'm trying to achieve something like the following:

```
<!-- a.html -->
<p>require('./b.html')</p>
<p>require('./c.html')</p>

<!-- b.html -->
Hello

<!-- c.html -->
World

// a.js
...
var html = require('[loader]!./a.html')
console.log(html)

#=> <p>Hello</p><p>World</p>
```

It seems like this should be doable, but I can't seem to get it to work in my configuration.  How might I go about getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) will be able to do this eventually. See [PR #41](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/pull/41) for details.